# How does Python (c) source code compiled into shared library

Tags: python, c, python-2.7

In Python 2.7 [`README`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/README#L782) file, it says

> Starting with Python 2.3, the majority of the interpreter can be built
>   into a shared library, which can then be used by the interpreter
>   executable

I want to know the following global variables in [`pystate.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/pystate.c#L49) are compiled into the shared library or the executable file?

```
static PyInterpreterState *interp_head = NULL;

PyThreadState *_PyThreadState_Current = NULL;
```

By the way, if such global(static) variables are compiled into shared library, does these states would be shared between different python processes? for example, [`pCryptGenRandom`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/random.c#L24) in [`random.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/random.c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both symbols are present in the zero-initialized segment of the shared library:

```
% nm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7_d.so|egrep '(interp_head|_PyThreadState_Current)'
000000000062a230 b interp_head
000000000062a208 B _PyThreadState_Current
```

The `interp_head` is a static variable - a variable without external linkage - and is not visible outside the module. `_PyThreadState_Current` has external linkage and is visible to the program using the shared library:

```
% objdump -TC /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 | \
   egrep 'interp_head|_PyThreadState_Current'
000000000056d3c0 g    DO .bss   0000000000000008  Base        _PyThreadState_Current
```

(Only `_PyThreadState_Current` is listed in the external symbol table).

---

Each process will have a separate set of global variables; these are not shared among Python processes.